# I need a count of serial numbers (last 6 months) that are under warranty for a failure rate report

Tags: sql

My table has the following columns:

```
SerialNo
ProductNo
WarrantyBeginDt
WarrantyEndDT
```

I would like to get a monthly in warranty count looking back about 6 months. I know how to get a month by specifying in the where clause. Would like to have a query that generates the last 6 months with out having to specify the month in the where clause.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Supplemental_Warranty
WHERE WarrantyBeginDt <= '6-15-2022' AND WarrantyEndDt >= '6-15-2022'
```

How could I create a query that looks back 6 months from the current date?

Comment: "6-15-2022" doesn't look like a valid date.

Comment: it works for me. WHERE WarrantyEndDt = '6-15-2022'

Comment: Date functions normally would depend on the `DBMS` you are using. What is yours, can you add a Tag like `postgresql` or whatever you use to your question?

Comment: If you are just comparing dates for equality, the format doesn't matter as long it's consistent. `<=` and `>=` I expect would go by lexicographic order, which wouldn't work with that format.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED to add group by month for 6 months to get count by month.

This should give you 6 months worth of data using system date (subtract 6 months from today) and end date/time is now so you dont have to specify specific dates, just using date add functionality to subtract 6 months from stating date.

```
SELECT count(*), MONTH(WarrantyBeginDt) AS CountPerMonth
FROM Supplemental_Warranty 
WHERE WarrantyBeginDt BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
--if you have any flags or other logic to identify if it is underwarranty or not
AND IsUnderWarranty = 1
GROUP BY MONTH(WarrantyBeginDt)
```

NOTE:  Not tested but this should do it depending on your SQL technology.

Comment: I know how to go back 6 months. My question is how do I count the number of serial numbers under warranty for a  particular month. Using WarrantyEndDt and WarrnantyBeginDT. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I updated my answer, if there is not any logic to identify if it is under warranty or not (just if it is in the date span) then the above should do it for you.